# Is this possible with elasticsearch?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Below is sample format of my JSON documents which is stored inside elasticsearch.

```
{
    "_index": "in22",
    "_type": "event",
    "_id": "ET00009709",
    "_version": 1,
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "Group": "Event",
        "Title": "Jurassic World",
        "_boost": 3,
        "inner_hits": [
            {
            "Code": "ET00009709",
            "IsDefault": "",
            "Language": "English",
            "Format": "3D",
            "Region": "MUMBAI"
        },
        {
            "Code": "ET00009710",
            "IsDefault": "Y",
            "Language": "English",
            "Format": "2D",
            "Region": "CHEN"
        },
        {
            "Code": "ET00009713",
            "IsDefault": "",
            "Language": "Hindi",
            "Format": "2D",
            "Region": "MUMBAI"
        },
        {
            "Code": "ET00009714",
            "IsDefault": "",
            "Language": "Tamil",
            "Format": "3D",
            "Region": "MUMBAI"
        },
        {
            "Code": "ET00009715",
            "IsDefault": "",
            "Language": "Hindi",
            "Format": "3D",
            "Region": "MUMBAI"
        },
        {
            "Code": "ET00009716",
            "IsDefault": "",
            "Language": "Bengali",
            "Format": "2D",
            "Region": "MUMBAI"
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now what I want to achieve is whenever I search for `Title=Jurassic World and region=MUMBAI`, I should get the above document but `inner_hits` should not contain

```
{
                "Code": "ET00009710",
                "IsDefault": "Y",
                "Language": "English",
                "Format": "2D",
                "Region": "CHEN"
 }
```

So is this achievable?

What I tries so far is

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "inner_hits",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "inner_hits.Region": "MUMBAI"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I couldn't achieve what i wanted, it didn't at all removed that block which contains `Region: Chen`

If anyone knows how to work around with this, please share.
Thanks

Comment: which version of elasticsearch ?

Comment: @keety ES Version: 1.5.2

Answer (score 1):

one work around is to use the [inner_hit](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html) feature added in elasticsearch 1.5.
This returns the nested documents which matched the nested query.

Example:

```
   {
   "_source": {
      "exclude": ["inner_hits.*"]
   },
   "query": {
      "nested": {
         "path": "inner_hits",
         "query": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "match": {
                        "inner_hits.Region": "MUMBAI"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         "inner_hits": {
              "size" : 10
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Response

```
"hits": [
     {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "test",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 3.8630462,
        "_source": {
           "Group": "Event",
           "_boost": 3,
           "inner_hits": [],
           "Title": "Jurassic World"
        },
        "inner_hits": {
           "inner_hits": {
              "hits": {
                 "total": 2,
                 "max_score": 3.8630462,
                 "hits": [
                    {
                       "_index": "test",
                       "_type": "test",
                       "_id": "1",
                       "_nested": {
                          "field": "inner_hits",
                          "offset": 2
                       },
                       "_score": 3.8630462,
                       "_source": {
                          "Code": "ET00009713",
                          "IsDefault": "",
                          "Language": "Hindi",
                          "Format": "2D",
                          "Region": "MUMBAI"
                       }
                    },
                    {
                       "_index": "test",
                       "_type": "test",
                       "_id": "1",
                       "_nested": {
                          "field": "inner_hits",
                          "offset": 0
                       },
                       "_score": 3.8630462,
                       "_source": {
                          "Code": "ET00009709",
                          "IsDefault": "",
                          "Language": "English",
                          "Format": "3D",
                          "Region": "MUMBAI"
                       }
                    }
                 ]
              }
           }
        }
     }
  ]
```

There is an additional `inner_hits` in the response besides the  `_source` which contains only the nested documents that matched. By default `inner_hits` returns the top 3 nested docs. You can tweak this with the [size](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html#_options) option.

Comment: First of all thanks, we are one step closer to our actual goal, please now consider the updated doc (i have edited doc in question), index it, use your search query, it will show hits total=5(which is correct there are 5 sub-doc which has `Region=MUMBAI`), but when you will query ES output produced will contain only 3 nested doc which has Region=MUMBAI instead of 5, may I know the reason behind that kind of working?

Comment: by default [inner_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html#_options) returns the top three documents . you can use `size` option to tweak it. I have edited the answer to show this